# Ubuntu UFW: how to add ipv6 tcp/udp rule?

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

For example, what is the ipv6 only equivalence of `ufw allow 22/tcp`?
UFW documentation does not list valid protocol names, and I could not figure out the protocol name for tcpv6.

Comment: This will work `ufw allow from ::/0 to any port 22 proto tcp`

Answer (score 2):

To allow IPv6 through the firewall, first perquisite is to add to
`/etc/default/ufw` the following line:

```
IPV6= yes
```

From now on, the syntax for `ufw allow` is exactly the same,
with IPv6 addresses used instead of IPv4.

For example, to allow all link-local addresses :

```
ufw allow from fe80::/64
```

Comment: It does not answer the question. e.g. what is the ipv6 only equivalence of "ufw allow 22/tcp"?

Comment: As I said, the syntax is exactly the same. If you would like to restrict the port to certain IP or IPs, you may use IPv6 addresses.

Comment: For IPv6, ports work the same as IPv4. Because these are in a new address family, there are now four separate port spaces. For example, there are two TCP port 80 spaces to which an application can bind, one in AF_INET and one in AF_INET6.

Comment: So how make this example to be ipv6 only: "ufw allow 22/tcp"?

Comment: The above command works for both. To make it IPv6-only, you need to apply it to a range of IPv6 addresses : `sudo ufw allow from IPv6-range to any port 22`.